# Should I store php/mysql modules in database or files?

Tags: php, mysql, php-extension

I have 10 different modules that are created to be used for the index page. I've created a jquery drop/sort function for the backend, so the admin of the site can change the layout of the front page without coding knowledge. However I'm having a problem finding a way to store the modules.

I have two types of modules:
1. An image, title, link and a **dynamic php/mysql generated content** (eg. last five reviews)
2. An image, title, link and **plain text**

What is the best way to store the modules that makes it possible to edit them easily in the backend? Should I store the php/mysql part in seperate php files or in mysql?

Any tips on making a good backend module solution would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that your filesystem is merely a database that has been highly optimised for retrieving files.

Comment: and the database stores all its data in files (ok memory to) :-)

Comment: If the admin does not have much coding knowledge, I would not trust the admin to edit php files. You should make your includes as flexible as possible so that they can be configured with preferences from a database that the admin can set.

Comment: @jeroen Can you elaborate your answers.. what do you mean by configure with preferences from a database that the admin can set? Any examples, tutorials etc that you can refer me to?

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing your files in your filesystem, and your data in the database. That is how it is designed. You may slow things down if you put your files into the database.

Comment: So if I want to edit the php module code I read/write to the file?

Comment: Yes, that is generally how it is done. Apache/PHP read from files on the filesystem. If you dynamically load from a database you have to eval() everything. This is a quirky way to do it. It can be done, but that is generally is reserved for view code in a more advanced CMS.